# Script to "hide" cookie tag for "x" minutes for retargeting purposes

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cookies

Me and my friend have developed a script that hide the cookie tag for "X" minutes because the whole concept is when a visitor visit my website I don't want to cookied immediately for retargeting proposes but to hide the cookie tag for x seconds so only I can cookied only the visitor that stays more than x seconds.

Check the code below:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Inject() {
$('body').append(HERE WE PUT THE RETARGETING PIXEL CODE);           
      }
        // run script after 45 sec.
        window.setTimeout(Inject, 45000);
    </script>
```

As you can see the retargeting pixel code goes between ( ) but the problem I am facing this moment is that when I place the retargeting pixel from Facebook inside the ( ) it seems that it doesn't work correctly. Check the image below to see how it looks like in my website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1KtE.png

As you can see something in the code is missing but I don't know what. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does 'I don't want to cookied immediately ...' Is that even a verb ? What does 'retargeting pixel code' mean ? PS: you could simply place the error code instead of that spam image.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle - one of the great things about English is that any noun can be verbed.

Comment: In that case, you might want to consider adding an auxiliary verb such as 'to be'. E.g: 'I don't want to to be cookied'. (Whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

Put a `document.cookie` assignment inside your timeout, no need for other functions:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     document.cookie = "key=value;path=/;expires="+someDateFunc();
 }, 45000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot tells me that you are closing the string in your `append()`-statement too soon. This is due a mismatch in your `'` and `"` signs.

Try this while being careful of my `'`-sign:

```
function Inject() {
    var img = new Image(1,1); // width, height values are optional params 
    img.src = 'http://www.your_facebook_img_link.com';
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

window.setTimeout(Inject, 45000);
```

This is pure JS and does not require jQuery.